# Loading data in select with Ajax / jQuery on click resets to the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Load data into a select with ajax and jQuery.

When I click on any item loaded the selection returns to the first item. Here is the code I use:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="selector-asesor-independiente">
     <label class="fl ml4p sitecolor">Asesor Independiente
          <select name="pol_drectivo" id="pol_drectivo" class="w100p"></select>
     </label>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('.selector-asesor-independiente select').click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "ajax_cargaAsesorIndependiente.php",
                            success: function(response)
                            {
                                $('.selector-asesor-independiente select').html(response).fadeIn();
                            }
                    });

                });
 });
```

I try to change the event from .click to .change but nothing happens. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you trying to fetch results on clicking of select box and then populating that select box again ?

Comment: The flow is as follows:
There are users who always have open that page to fill out insurance policies and there are other users that feed select from another page. That's why charge data when they click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended to call the ajax on `document.ready()` method or `window.load`. Not on the `click` of the same input.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        //Your ajax call here
    });
```

If this doesn't help, please post a sample of the response you are getting.

***Updated code:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_cargaAsesorIndependiente.php",
        success: function(response) {
            $('.selector-asesor-independiente select').html(response).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This happens: https://gyazo.com/0197316bd319999651e8b2303e0a90a9 (Its a gif with the response)

Comment: This is happening even after you changed your event to doc ready function? 

can you please update the question to your new code ?

Comment: Yes, after i do it.

Comment: Oh I can see that you left the click event, you need to remove it. I update it my answer to suit your needs

Comment: The problem is i need to update the select in the click event to be always updated

Comment: but the mechanism is illogical. 

you are facing the problem because ajax is asynchronous. the click does not wait for the ajax to load then display the items. 

the dropdown displays the items while the ajax call is being made. when the ajax call finishes, it's being re-drawn if you will, thus the result is being reset.

Comment: Few alternative suggestions: 
option 1:  have a timer that refresh the dropdown every x seconds.
option 2:  save the value of the current selected item, re-select it when the ajax loads
option 3: have a reload button to reload the drop down.
option 4: refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks, the third option was used